# Ubuntu bash functions..syntax error: "(" or "}" unexpected

Tags: bash, scripts

Trying to run some bash functions , but keep encountering syntax error: "(" unexpected.
I've try'ed removing the brackets,parenthesis etc etc...nothing seems to work.

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1) release
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello () {
echo "Hello world"
}
```

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: With full permissions. sh hello.sh

Comment: see ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-functaions.php

Comment: I read his tutorials last night and followed them to see where I was going wrong...but I still get a syntax error which is very confusing. Should't the shebang at least make the function compatible even if Ubuntu is running a different shell?

Comment: Problem solved. I was using $ sh hello.sh ---> I get error . I should of been using ./hello.sh to run it correctly.I'm guessing the shebang gets over written and the default dash shell used?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are running the script with `sh hello.sh`, the interpreting shell will not be the one mentioned in the shebang line, but `/bin/sh` will be used. In case of Debian and Ubuntu by default this will be `dash`.

So to run your script correctly with a `bash`, use either of the following.

```
/bin/bash hello.sh
```

or

```
chmod +x hello.sh
./hello.sh
```

Alternatively you also could set `bash` as the `/bin/sh`.

```
dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

Comment: Thank you for response.No idea why it was down voted :/

Comment: @JamesA presumably because setting `/bin/sh` to be bash will affect *everything* and not just this particular script, and as is obvious from the question, the two have different behaviours and there's no telling what might break from such a change.

Answer (score 5):

**First:**

The syntax error is because of (). Remove () from the file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello {
echo "Hello world"
}
```

or you can just run the following command to edit the file for you:

```
sed -i 's/() //g' hello.sh
```

You should now be able to run the file with the desired result.

---

**Alternatively**:

You could add lines 2, 3, and 4 to your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
function hello () {
echo "Hello world"
}
```

Remember, **do not** use `sudo` to edit your `~/.bashrc` file!

After you add the lines to the file, run the following command to restart bash or "source" your .bashrc file:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

You should now be able to run the comand `hello` and "Hello world" should print in the terminal.

---

**Also:**

You could edit the file to say this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
```

and name the file `hello` and save the file to `/usr/local/bin`.

After doing all of that, make the file executable by running the following command:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/hello
```

You should now be able to run the comand `hello` and "Hello world" should print in the terminal.

---

**Finally:**

A third option would be to add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias hello='echo "Hello world"'
```

Then, source your .bashrc file using the following command:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you for you responses....I've tried a few  and found the answer simple enough. Instead of using $sh hello.sh... ./hello.sh works fine.It must be the shebang been over written ^^

Comment: Why was Thomas's answer down voted but? Was he not correct?

Answer (score 3):

GNU Bash is the shell used by default in terminals on Ubuntu. However when scripts are executed on system boot then dash is used, as it is dash that is /bin/sh.

Won't work-->

```
$ sh hello.sh
```

Will work -->

```
$./hello.sh
```

Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

According to your Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function hello () {
    echo "Hello world"
}

#call this function as follow:
hello   # Syntax Correct
hello() # Syntax Error
```